# java chat socket trouble

Tags: java, sockets, chat

I am working on multi chat in java. I'm kinda new to this socket thing.
There is a problem with my code but I can't find it. I think the problem is in clientSocket.getInputStream(); . I inserted System.out.println before and after this statement. I can't see the second one. It seems that client can connect to port but cannot get inputs from server. If you can help me, I really would be thankful. It has been 3 hours but still I can't find the problem

ClientSide.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;




public class ClientSide 
{

    public Socket clientSocket;
    public ObjectOutputStream outStream;
    public ObjectInputStream inStream;
    public String receiveMessage=null,sendMessage=null;
    public GuiScreen gui;


    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 2222);

            inStream = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            outStream.flush();


            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    receiveMessage = (String)inStream.readObject();
                    gui.appendMessage(receiveMessage);
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException classNot)
                {System.err.println("data received in unknown format");}
            }
        }

        catch(UnknownHostException unknownHost)
        {System.err.println("You are trying to connect to an unknown host!");}
        catch(IOException ioException)
        {ioException.printStackTrace();}


    }

    public String readMessage()
    {
        String text = "";

        try 
        {
            text =  (String)inStream.readObject();
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}

        return text;
    }


    public void sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        try
        {
            outStream.writeObject(msg);
            outStream.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){ioException.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public ClientSide()
    {}

    private void showGui()
    {
        gui = new GuiScreen(this,"Client Side");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClientSide client = new ClientSide();
        client.showGui();
        client.run();

    }

}
```

MultiCheatServer.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MultiChatServer 
{
    public static ClientThread[] clientThreads = new ClientThread[10];

    public static int portNumber = 2222;
    public static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    public static Socket clientSocket = null;

    public static void openPort()
    {
        try 
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {e.printStackTrace();}

    }

    public static void connectToClients()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try 
            {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {e.printStackTrace();}


            for(int i = 0; i<=9; ++i)
            {
                if(clientThreads[i] == null)
                {
                    clientThreads[i] = new ClientThread(clientSocket,clientThreads);
                    clientThreads[i].start();

                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        openPort();
        connectToClients();

    }
}
```

ClientThread.java

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ClientThread extends Thread
{
    public ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
    public ObjectOutputStream outStream = null;

    public Socket clientSocket;
    public ClientThread[] clientThreads;

    public ClientThread (Socket cSocket,ClientThread[] cThreads)
    {
        clientSocket = cSocket;
        clientThreads = cThreads;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        try 
        {
            outStream.writeObject(msg);
            outStream.flush();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {e.printStackTrace();}

    }

    public String readMessage()
    {
        String text = null;

        try 
        {
            text =  (String)inStream.readObject();
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}

        return text;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String text; 
        String name;

        try 
        {
            inStream = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            outStream= new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            outStream.flush();

            sendMessage("Name:\n");
            name = readMessage().trim();
            sendMessage("type /quit if you want to quit\n");

            for(int i = 0 ; i <=9 ; ++i)
                if(clientThreads[i]!=null && clientThreads[i]!=this)
                    clientThreads[i].sendMessage(name + "has come\n");

            while(true)
            {
                text = readMessage() ;

                if(text.startsWith("/quit"))
                    break;

                for(int i = 0; i<=9; ++i)
                    if(clientThreads[i] != null)
                        clientThreads[i].sendMessage("<" + name + ">" + text);
            }

            for(int i = 0 ;i<=9; ++i)
                if(clientThreads[i]!=null && clientThreads[i]!=this)
                    clientThreads[i].sendMessage(name + " has disconnected\n");
            sendMessage("Bye\n");


            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            for(int i = 0;i<=9;++i)
                if(clientThreads[i]==this)
                    clientThreads[i] = null;


        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {e.printStackTrace();}

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an exception? You might also consider making an [SSCCE](http://ssccce.org) of your problem.

Comment: yeah I'm getting an exception:
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

And what is SSCCE btw

Comment: Put the entire stack trace in your question, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example. (I just realized that I messed up the link on the first one, this one works.)

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that you have to **decide who creates the input stream first**, the server or the client.

`ObjectInputStream` tries to read a serialization header in its constructor, and if the output stream has not written it yet it will wait. Now both client and server are waiting for the other to "speak" first.